# Setting a custom base in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, radix

I'm trying to build a custom base that consist of 31 characters:

```
$custom_array = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
"b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n"
,"p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z");
```

I excluded vowels from the alphabet and added numbers at the begining.

Well, basically i need a function that is similar to base_convert(), so that i can convert to base10 and vice versa.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:
I came up with this function but the accepted answer is also a good approach. Thanks.

```
$basearray = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z");

function baseXto10($code,$basearray)
{
    $codearr = array_reverse(str_split($code));
    $charnum = count($basearray);
    $sum = 0;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($codearr as $key => $value)
    {
        $charpos = array_search($basearray, $value);
        $sum+= $charpos * pow($charnum,$i);
        $i++;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Comment: put your expected output here also. more easy to get solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use base_convert() for converting between actual bases. Then, from base10 (or any for that matter) map the values between the initial and your new base.

Perhaps something like this

```
function my_base_convert($input, $fromBase) 
{ 
   $baseMapping = [
      '0' => 0,
      'a' => 'b',
      //etc
   ];

   $result = base_convert($input, $fromBase, 10);

   return str_replace(array_keys($baseMapping), array_values($baseMapping), $input);
}
```

Then simple str_replace

Comment: i think your approach may solve my problem, thank you!